# error when referencing cell value that contains sheet id?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UVsnY59g8l5kkGbe1lOqrQVbHz8pIj6eFF1COWdQZN8/edit?usp=sharing

On one sheet, I have a  blank field, where a user can paste a sheet key, and click a button.

In the box below, it should display the current sheet key, so that a user can copy and paste to a newer copy of the workbook. I pieced together a script which is below, but in the second box where the current sheet key should be is an error: you do not have permission to call spreadsheetapp.openbyid. Trying the run the script gives me this:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.

```
//variables
var id = "123456789abcdefg";
var sheet = "LOG WIZARD";
var cells = "M11:AB13";
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(cells);
var id = range.getSheet().getParent().getId();

//custom function to import logs
function importlogs() {

//Source sheet from which to import from
var is = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
var sheet1i = is.getSheetByName("BUDGET LOG");
var sheet2i = is.getSheetByName("LOG");

//Current sheet from which to export to
var xs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1x = xs.getSheetByName("BUDGET LOG");
var sheet2x = xs.getSheetByName("LOG");

//Copy and paste contents of import Budget Log sheet to export Budget Log sheet
sheet1i.getRange("A3:AO").copyTo(sheet1x.getRange(sheet1x.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});

//Copy and paste contents of import Log sheet to export Log sheet
sheet2i.getRange("A3:O").copyTo(sheet2x.getRange(sheet2x.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: See  [tagging](/help/tagging)

Comment: You can just provide the row and column of the upper left cell in the destination range.  As it stands not your specified range is too small to fit your data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that, but still same error.